# Error Server Status 1

Tags: mongodb

I don't have root access to the server I have the MongoDB in. Therefore, I need to tell the administrator how to set up MongoDB correctly so I can make use of it.

I'm receiving this error:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on admin to execute
>   command { serverStatus: 1 }

The script I'm trying to execute is form this site: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
    # pprint library is used to make the output look more pretty
    from pprint import pprint
    # connect to MongoDB, change the << MONGODB URL >> to reflect your own connection string
    client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
    db=client.admin
    # Issue the serverStatus command and print the results
    serverStatusResult=db.command("serverStatus")
    pprint(serverStatusResult)
```

Things I have tried to debug it:

1. Check the service is running. It is, in fact running, that's the way I retrieved the connection URL.
2. Gave 777 permissions to my python script.

Again, I don't have permissions to edit or configure MongoDB directly. I can type mongo in the terminal and see it is connecting. I assume the admin needs to create a db user with all the privileges ( I will be doing the administration for this database).  To decrease back and forth communication I want to check if that's the case and if that's the case how would I go about doing that.

MondoDB is installed in Open Suse Leap 42.3 OS.

Thanks

Comment: The error message from PyMongo is the result of attempting to execute a command on your MongoDB deployment, so it appears that you are able to connect and just need to authenticate with credentials that have appropriate privileges. Your MongoDB administrator can either grant a built-in role or create a custom role for the commands that you require:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/. The `serverStatus` command applies to the overall deployment (rather than a specific database) so the scope of this will be at at the `cluster` resource level.

Comment: If you are only running that script as an example (rather than specifically needing to run the `serverStatus` command) you might find the [PyMongo tutorial](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) a better starting point for learning about working with MongoDB.

Comment: You mention you will be "doing the administration for this database" and would like guidance on what to request from the current admin. Can you clarify what level of access you want to request and the version of MongoDB used? For example, do you need full access for a specific database but ability to monitor the overall deployment (which may have multiple databases)? I do think it would be more effective for you to describe/discuss your requirements with your admin directly, as they should already have the context for configuration and security of the deployment they are managing.

Comment: Thank you Stennie. Very useful advice. I will need the ability to monitor the overall deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You are running mongod with [enabled authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/).

To execute `serverStatus` command you need to log in as a user with either [clusterAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterAdmin) or [clusterMonitor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterMonitor) role.